# How to use linear regression for prediction

Tags: self-study

A taxi company monitoring the safety of its cabs kept track of the number of miles tires had been driven (in thousands) and the depth of the tread remaining (in mm).  Their data are displayed in the scatter plot.  They found the correlation to be $r = –0.86$ and the equation of the regression line to be $tread = 36 - 0.6 \cdot miles$.

Use the equation to predict the tread for a car driven $25$ thousand miles.

Use the equation to predict the tread for a car driven $45$ thousand miles.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

Some hints to start with:

- you have two $miles$ value
- you must provide two $tread$ value
- you have an equation $tread = 36 - 0.6 \cdot miles$

Any idea?

Comment: Thank you for providing hints only, that is our [policy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Please do not "write a more detailed answer later". This question should have been closed earlier, nothing more should be put until the OP has made the required changes.

Comment: OK, removing that part.